# create local user without changeing password after login

Tags: powershell

i have a little gui script for creating local users under various circumstances. actually i have a problem adding a further switch to my script for creating a account without a password and the opportunity to change the password after login. what do i need to add that this can be realized. this is what i have

```
    $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

# restart elevated if needed
if(!(new-object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal([System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())).IsInRole(544)){
    start powershell -Verb runas -ArgumentList '-File',$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
    exit
}

#####################################################################################################################################################

#create form
$form             = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Width       = 500
$form.Height      = 600
$form.MaximizeBox = $false
$form.TopMost     = $true

#####################################################################################################################################################

$objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.label
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20)
$objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(130,15)
$objLabel.BackColor = "Transparent"
$objLabel.ForeColor = "Black"
$objLabel.Text = "Username"
$Form.Controls.Add($objLabel)

#textbox with choosen user name
$txtBox          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$txtBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point (180, 20)
$txtBox.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,100)
$form.Controls.Add($txtBox)

#####################################################################################################################################################

$objLabel2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.label
$objLabel2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,50)
$objLabel2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(130,15)
$objLabel2.BackColor = "Transparent"
$objLabel2.ForeColor = "Black"
$objLabel2.Text = "Password"
$Form.Controls.Add($objLabel2)

#textbox with choosen password 
$txtBox2          = New-Object Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox
$txtBox2.PasswordChar = '*'  
$txtBox2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point (180, 50)
$txtBox2.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,100)
$form.Controls.Add($txtBox2)


#####################################################################################################################################################

#create checkbox1
$checkBox          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$checkBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point (10, 100)
$checkBox.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(350,30)
$checkBox.Text     = "PasswordNeverExpires"
$form.Controls.Add($checkBox)


#create checkbox2
$checkBox2          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$checkBox2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point (10, 150)
$checkBox2.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(350,30)
$checkBox2.Text     = "UserMayChangePassword"
$form.Controls.Add($checkBox2)

#create checkbox3
$checkBox3          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$checkBox3.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point (10, 200)
$checkBox3.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(350,30)
$checkBox3.Text     = "AccountNeverExpires"
$form.Controls.Add($checkBox3)

#create checkbox4
$checkBox4          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$checkBox4.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point (10, 250)
$checkBox4.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(350,30)
$checkBox4.Text     = "AdminAccount"
$form.Controls.Add($checkBox4)

#create checkbox5
$checkBox5          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$checkBox5.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point (10, 300)
$checkBox5.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(350,30)
$checkBox5.Text     = "noPassword"
$checkbox5.Add_Click({
    # disable/enable other controls depending on state of current checkbox
        $checkBox.Enabled = !$checkBox5.Checked
        $txtBox2.Enabled = !$checkBox5.Checked
        $checkbox4.Enabled = !$checkBox5.Checked
})

$form.Controls.Add($checkBox5)

#create user button
$Button          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,350)
$Button.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,50)
$Button.Text     = "create user"
$Button.Add_Click({
    # Admin or Users Group
    $group = @{$true='S-1-5-32-544';$false='S-1-5-32-545'}[$checkbox4.checked]
    try{
        # define options to create user
        $useroptions = @{
            Name = $txtbox.Text
            Description = $txtbox.Text
            Fullname = $txtbox.Text
            AccountNeverExpires = $checkbox3.Checked
            UserMayNotChangePassword = !$checkbox2.Checked
        }
    # if the "noPassword" checkbox is not checked
        if (!$checkbox5.Checked){
            $useroptions.Password = ConvertTo-SecureString $txtbox2.Text -AsPlainText -Force
            $useroptions.PasswordNeverExpires = $checkbox.Checked
        }else{
        # "noPassword" checkbox is checked
            $useroptions.NoPassword = $true           
            $group = 'S-1-5-32-545'
        }
        # create user and assign to administrators group
        New-LocalUser @useroptions | Add-LocalGroupMember -Group (Get-Localgroup | ? Sid -eq $group)
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("User has been created successfully.","User created",0,64)
    }catch{
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Error creating new user account:`n $($_.Exception.Message)","Exception",0,48)
    }


})
$form.Controls.Add($Button)

#end
[void]$form.ShowDialog()`$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

# restart elevated if needed
if(!(new-object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal([System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())).IsInRole(544)){
    start powershell -Verb runas -ArgumentList '-File',$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
    exit
}

#####################################################################################################################################################

#create form
$form             = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Width       = 500
$form.Height      = 600
$form.MaximizeBox = $false
$form.TopMost     = $true

#####################################################################################################################################################

$objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.label
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20)
$objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(130,15)
$objLabel.BackColor = "Transparent"
$objLabel.ForeColor = "Black"
$objLabel.Text = "Username"
$Form.Controls.Add($objLabel)

#textbox with choosen user name
$txtBox          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$txtBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point (180, 20)
$txtBox.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,100)
$form.Controls.Add($txtBox)

#####################################################################################################################################################

$objLabel2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.label
$objLabel2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,50)
$objLabel2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(130,15)
$objLabel2.BackColor = "Transparent"
$objLabel2.ForeColor = "Black"
$objLabel2.Text = "Password"
$Form.Controls.Add($objLabel2)

#textbox with choosen password 
$txtBox2          = New-Object Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox
$txtBox2.PasswordChar = '*'  
$txtBox2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point (180, 50)
$txtBox2.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,100)
$form.Controls.Add($txtBox2)


#####################################################################################################################################################

#create checkbox1
$checkBox          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$checkBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point (10, 100)
$checkBox.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(350,30)
$checkBox.Text     = "PasswordNeverExpires"
$form.Controls.Add($checkBox)


#create checkbox2
$checkBox2          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$checkBox2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point (10, 150)
$checkBox2.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(350,30)
$checkBox2.Text     = "UserMayChangePassword"
$form.Controls.Add($checkBox2)

#create checkbox3
$checkBox3          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$checkBox3.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point (10, 200)
$checkBox3.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(350,30)
$checkBox3.Text     = "AccountNeverExpires"
$form.Controls.Add($checkBox3)

#create checkbox4
$checkBox4          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$checkBox4.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point (10, 250)
$checkBox4.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(350,30)
$checkBox4.Text     = "AdminAccount"
$form.Controls.Add($checkBox4)

#create checkbox5
$checkBox5          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$checkBox5.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point (10, 300)
$checkBox5.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(350,30)
$checkBox5.Text     = "noPassword"
$checkbox5.Add_Click({
    # disable/enable other controls depending on state of current checkbox
        $checkBox.Enabled = !$checkBox5.Checked
        $txtBox2.Enabled = !$checkBox5.Checked
        $checkbox4.Enabled = !$checkBox5.Checked
})

$form.Controls.Add($checkBox5)

#create user button
$Button          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,350)
$Button.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,50)
$Button.Text     = "create user"
$Button.Add_Click({
    # Admin or Users Group
    $group = @{$true='S-1-5-32-544';$false='S-1-5-32-545'}[$checkbox4.checked]
    try{
        # define options to create user
        $useroptions = @{
            Name = $txtbox.Text
            Description = $txtbox.Text
            Fullname = $txtbox.Text
            AccountNeverExpires = $checkbox3.Checked
            UserMayNotChangePassword = !$checkbox2.Checked
        }
    # if the "noPassword" checkbox is not checked
        if (!$checkbox5.Checked){
            $useroptions.Password = ConvertTo-SecureString $txtbox2.Text -AsPlainText -Force
            $useroptions.PasswordNeverExpires = $checkbox.Checked
        }else{
        # "noPassword" checkbox is checked
            $useroptions.NoPassword = $true           
            $group = 'S-1-5-32-545'
        }
        # create user and assign to administrators group
        New-LocalUser @useroptions | Add-LocalGroupMember -Group (Get-Localgroup | ? Sid -eq $group)
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("User has been created successfully.","User created",0,64)
    }catch{
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Error creating new user account:`n $($_.Exception.Message)","Exception",0,48)
    }


})
$form.Controls.Add($Button)

#end
[void]$form.ShowDialog()`
```

Comment: For that you need to add these to your `$useroptions`Hashtable: `UserMayNotChangePassword = $false; NoPassword = $true` and leave out: `PasswordNeverExpires` and `Password` elements. See [New-LocalUser the second syntax block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/new-localuser?view=powershell-5.1#syntax)

Comment: @Theo but i want a account without password. i just don't want the opportunity the need to change the password after logon